# GeoServer intersect filter error with SQL view publish

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have created a GeoServer service with a SQL view. The service is serving rivers. I want to select rivers in a polygon. So I am trying GeoServer demo request tool.

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  outputFormat="GML2"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
    http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:rivers">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4321">
          <gml:exterior>
            <gml:LinearRing>
              <gml:posList>78.57 58.32 78.48 24.7 96.89 81.23 51.61 62.41 08.42</gml:posList>
            </gml:LinearRing>
          </gml:exterior>
        </gml:Polygon>
      </ogc:Intersects>
   </ogc:Filter>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

This request gives an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOException null ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
```

If my request goes to a service that not created with aSQL view, it works. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when postgres is trying to apply a spatial index with a geometry having one srid, but the
data has another.

Are you using a sql view? If so, maybe you setup the wrong srid when creating the sql view?
If instead it's a normal view, may it be there are geometries in different srids in it?
Postgis has a function to check the srid of a geometry, you should check.

Another possibility for the difference is that qgis is not using any spatial filter... but that would be rather strange.

If you look at **Coordinate Reference Systems**  you see

- Native SRS
- Declared SRS

  you should specify declared SRS or Native SRS not both of them.